# Why is Sir Walter's statement said "sarcastically" in Austen's "Persuasion"?

Tags: jane-austen, persuasion

In Jane Austen's *Persuasion*, when discussing possible tenants for Kellynch Hall, the possibility of leasing the house to a captain in the navy is brought up. Sir Walter then makes this comment:

> Sir Walter only nodded. But soon afterwards, rising and pacing the room, he observed sarcastically:
> 'There are few among the gentlemen of the navy, I imagine, who would not be surprized to find themselves in a house of this description.'
> <sub>*Persuasion*, chapter 3</sub>

Everyone else, such as Mrs. Clay, treats this statement with full sincerity. Why is this remark said to be "sarcastic"? Is Austen using this term in a different sense than the modern usage of the word?

Answer (score 9):

Sir Walter is being snobbish at the expense of the officers of the Royal Navy, by saying that the majority of them would be overawed by the majesty of Kellynch Hall. This is “sarcastic” in the following sense:

> **sarcasm, *n.*** A sharp, bitter, or cutting expression or remark; a bitter gibe or taunt.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

Because sarcasm is so often accompanied with verbal irony (saying the opposite of what you mean), the word is often reserved for remarks that are sharp *and also ironic*, for example, Merriam–Webster’s first sense is:

> **sarcasm *noun* 1**: a sharp and often satirical or ironic utterance designed to cut or give pain.
>
> <sub>*Merriam–Webster Dictionary*.</sub>

Even in Austen’s day most remarks described as “sarcastic” respected this additional criterion, but here are a couple of examples in which irony does not seem to be intended:

> Rejoice, O young Man (says Solomon† in a severe **Sarcasm**) and let thy Heart chear thee in the Days of thy Youth, and walk in the Ways of thy Heart, and in the Sight of thine Eyes: But know thou, that for these Things God will bring thee into Judgment.
>
> <sub>John Rogers (1784). [*Nineteen Sermons on Several Occasions*, p. 251](https://archive.org/details/bim_eighteenth-century_nineteen-sermons-on-seve_rogers-john_1784/page/250/mode/2up). London: G. Robinson.</sub>
>
> <sub>† Rogers is quoting [Ecclesiastes 11:9](https://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/11-9.htm) here, in the Authorized Version.</sub>

> Dionysius, the tyrant of Syracuse, asked him [Aristippus] in a **sarcastic** manner the reason why philosophers were seen often at the gates of princes, but princes never at the doors of philosophers.
>
> <sub>Charles de Saint-Évremond. Quoted in anon., ed. (1805). [*The French Anas*, volume 3, p. 122](https://archive.org/details/frenchanas02perrgoog/page/n129/mode/2up). London: Richard Phillips.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

In the army of Jane Austen's time, officers had to buy their commissions, so you had to be wealthy to achieve high rank. Promotion in the navy was based more on merit - you had to pass an exam to become a lieutenant - though having influential family or friends certainly helped.

Sir Walter is implying that naval officers are likely to be of lower social status than his family, and not used to visiting the houses of titled people.

Comment: For clarity from:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_of_commissions_in_the_British_Army   Commissioned office in the English Army could be purchased for either infantry or cavalry regiments from the 17th to 19th centuries. This avoided the need to wait to be promoted for merit or seniority, and was the usual way to obtain a commission in the Army. The practice began in 1683 until abolished in 1871. Formally, the purchase price of a commission was a cash bond for good behaviour, liable to be forfeited if found guilty of cowardice, desertion, or gross misconduct.